# Why error "':' expected" when using null conditional in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

**UPDATE:** CodeCaster's comment was correct, had to do with me being on TypeScript 3.5 rather than 3.7+. I didn't suspect that cuz these checks seem to be working from the angular stuff, e.g. `<div *ngIf="parts?.length"></div>`.

---

I have some code in TypeScript that looks like this:

```
if (!this.session.draftData?.length) {
   return;
}
```

I've been using similar checks just fine elsewhere, but compiler gives me this error: `error TS1005: ':' expected.`

Comment: You need TypeScript 3.7 for that, which version are you on?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WG6VKm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: CodeCaster's comment is correct. The project I'm working in is using TypeScript 3.5. **Thanks!** It was confusing me cuz these checks are working in Angular checks e.g. `<div *ngIf="parts?.length"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **brackets** in your complete code, so that it is showing the error.
in my opinion